# How to redirect all requests to index page with original url

Tags: php, .htaccess

I need some suggestion on some htaccess rule. What I want is that all requests in my site will redirect to index.php. But also I need to log what url the user was trying to visit in my databse. 
So, say if someone try to visit a page in my site(which does not exists) like

> example.com/somefolder/somefile.php?somevar=someval&somevar2=someval2

then he will actually be redirected to *index.php* where I will need to somehow get and log the original full url in my database.

Hope I was able to clear my clear my requirement. Thanks.

Comment: Look up `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` and use it in `index.php` if I understood you correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Original URL is available to you in `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

Answer (score 0):

The above answer didn't work in my case so after a research I found this helpful and might be helpful for someone else too in future.

To redirect all requests to `index.php`, provide these lines in `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/index.php$
RewriteRule (.*) /index.php [R=301,L]
```

Remember this redirects all requests to `index.php` even if its your stylesheet.css or jquery.js